# How to exit a function in jQuery .on() function when a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript/jquery code.

I am a javascript newbie, so I apologize if this question is extremely easy to solve. 
I'd like to exit this .on('click') function if there is an error or if there is no key found on the server. This on click bind fires a post request on a form, so I'd like to continue running it if those two conditions are not met. I checked other examples and I tried numerous things like `return`, `.stopPropagation` etc.

How should I do that? I tried `return;` and `return false;` but it still refreshes the page and fires the post request on the form.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var validation = false;
    $('#submitform').on('click', function(e) {

        if (validation === true) {
            validation = false; // reset flag
            return;// let the event bubble away
        }

        if ($('#street_number') == "" && $('#route') == "" && $('#lat') == "" && $('#lon') == ""
                && $('#administrative_area_level_1') == "") {
            alert("Unknown Address");
            validation = false;
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var data_dict = {
                // Number
                'street_number': $('#street_number').val(),
                // Address
                'address': $('#route').val(),
                // City
                'city': $('#locality').val(),
                // postal code
                'postal_code': $('#postal_code').val(),
                // State
                'state': $('#administrative_area_level_1').val(),
                // Country
                'country': $('#country').val()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/zillow_check/',
                data: data_dict,
                method: 'POST'
            }).then(function (response) {
                console.log("Checking for Zillow ID...");
                if (response.error) {
                    console.error("There was an error " + response.error);
                    $('.dashboard-main__appartment--input').addClass('serverError');
                    validation = false;
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("Zillow key: " + response);
                    if (response == 'No zillow ID found.') {
                        // You can change this to whatever you like.
                        alert("Can't add this object. It does not exist on Zillow. Check the Address and try again.");
                        validation = false;
                        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        return;

                    }
                    else if (isNaN(response) == false ) {
                        validation = true;
                        $('#propertyform').submit()
                    }
                }

            });

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default for all cases right away.

Ajax is asynchronous so you can't wait for it to complete to try to prevent the default then...it's too late.

```
$('#submitform').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // no need for other instances of preventDefault() beyond here or for `stopImmediatePropagation()`

    // your other code

})
```

Comment: I have tried that solution. Unfortunately, it does not submit the form after I put the ```e.preventDefault();``` where you suggested. Do I have to handle that case somehow differently?

Comment: you are submitting it in the ajax success callback with `$('#propertyform').submit()`. If that isn't working then you need to debug the other conditions

Comment: I've added console.log statement to that else block and it fires that statement properly, but it does not submit the form. If I remove the ```e.preventDefault()``` it works, but the other conditions in that case still submit the form, which brings us back to the original question.